# Increase auto-snap margin to sides of Form when placing controls

Tags: .net, winforms

When placing controls on a form, the ide helps out by autosnapping at places that make sense.  For a certain project I'm working on, I'd like to increase the autosnap distance to the sides of the form a little bit.  Is there a way to do this on the form level (i.e. not per control because that would defeat the purpose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, bump up the form's Padding property.